# Working Cron with Laravel on a shared server, gives this error, why?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

Good afternoon,

I am trying to run this cron to work with queues in laravel 5.6, in a host compared with laravel, but I get the following error:

```
[root@s19 ~]# /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/myweb/artisan schedule:run

   InvalidArgumentException  : 5 is not a valid position

  at /home/nigmacod/nigmacode/vendor/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/FieldFactory.php:46
    42|                 case 4:
    43|                     $this->fields[$position] = new DayOfWeekField();
    44|                     break;
    45|                 default:
  > 46|                     throw new InvalidArgumentException(
    47|                         $position . ' is not a validposition'
    48|                     );
    49|             }
    50|         }

  Exception trace:

  1   Cron\FieldFactory::getField()
      /home/user/myweb/vendor/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/CronExpression.php:153

  2   Cron\CronExpression::setPart("*")
      /home/user/myweb/vendor/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/CronExpression.php:136
```

that is function schedule in my kernel file:

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {

            $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
            ->cron('* * * * * *')
            ->withoutOverlapping();
        }
```

And this would be the cron that I have configured in my cpanel so that it runs every minute:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/myweb/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`->cron('* * * * * *')` is your issue.

Cron expects five values - minute, hour, day of the month, month, and day of the week. You've provided a sixth, and it doesn't know what to do with it.

Change it to `->cron('* * * * *')` (or for better readability, `->everyMinute()`) and you'll be all set.

Comment: I am having a problem with `->everyMinute()` command in Laravel that I need to convert it to `->cron()`. Any idea?

Comment: @Player1 Converting it is unlikely to help - `everyMinute` is just an alias for `->cron('* * * * *')`, so whatever's broken will still be broken.

Comment: Yes, I should find the root of the problem.